# Sorting Images on Android

Tags: android

I need images to be sorted by folders. like drawable/Photos, drawable/items, drawable/photos. and put each folder to the registry or at least find way to get them out of there. all I want is something close to php like "../img/photos/photo0.jpg". is there way to do something like this. and folder with Images must contain in apk file.

possible solutions is make link in the R file but I didn't find how to do it, other solution is find command with logic like I will show you here:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)CloningTable.findViewById(R.id.img); 
String ImgPath = "com.test.test/img/img0.jpg";
img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImgPath));
```

OR

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)CloningTable.findViewById(R.id.img);
String ImgPath = "com.test.test/img/img0.jpg";
img.setImageResource(ImgPath);
```

please say me the best way to handle it. AND specify if it contain path how I can know path the file lies in.

```
File ImgFile = new File("test/test.jpg");
TextView testtext = (TextView)CloningTable.findViewById(R.id.testtext);
if (ImgFile.exists()) {
    test.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImgFile.getPath()));
    testtext.setText("asdasuidjasdk");
}
```

can any one say Why programm can't find file and file exist 100% = /?

filepath: Project> assets/test/test.jpg

---

found solution: [Android Show image by path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691295/android-show-image-by-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should put resources in assets folder, and you can access them by path!

So if you want to save the path string, the best way is creating a class, with 2 variants: 1 Bitmap to store data, and 1 String to store the path.

If not, just create a String array that you may access when you want.

In both case, you need to put the path into the Path String storage before you load the image.

Hope I understood your question.

EDIT: Final answer that meet your requirement:

There's no path for drawable, they are all converted into ID. If you put in asset folder, just call it by their name. For example, you have "Test.bmp" in asset folder, its path is "Test.bmp". If you have "SubTest.bmp" in "TestFolder" in asset folder, its path is "TestFolder/SubTest.bmp". Sorry for long time, I had to sleep, it was mid night at my time zone.

Comment: yes I know it but there is small problem I don't know how to generate that path. can you please write ?

Comment: As Aleadam said at the under post, you can use BitmapFactory to generate the image data from asset, or any source you like.

Comment: ok I had read all of that and there is almoust none information of making links to file or finding files by links. yes you can use comand getFilesPath(); but after what to do with that I NEED PATH. more than all other can any one show the right Way to show path I mean there is folder res/strings/string.xml is it any way to get the path where this file is containing ? I just don't know right way to show the right path. "com.test.test/res/strings/string.xml" it dosen't work like this so like what it works can any one just give ME THE PATH.

Comment: OK, so your main problem is, you need the EXACT ADDRESS of the IMAGE FILE, right? There's NO way to get the path from the loaded data (in this case, image). So if you need the path later, you MUST save it somewhere. Check again my answer, I will edit it.

Comment: yes you understood on 50% but can you show Path Excample or Bitmap please it would be wery nice if I would see how path must look excample place file in assets getFilesPath()+"/FilenameHere" Or ("com.test.test/FilenameHere"). so I could work out bitmap or any other ways to get any that works = /. couse it is to hard when you don't know exact path of that folder.

Comment: There's no path for drawable, they are all converted into ID. If you put in asset folder, just call it by their name. For example, you have "Test.bmp" in asset folder, its path is "Test.bmp". If you have "SubTest.bmp" in "TestFolder" in asset folder, its path is "TestFolder/SubTest.bmp". Sorry for long time, I had to sleep, it was mid night at my time zone.

Comment: AE AE AE AE AE that was exactly what I wanted = ] thnx = ]

Comment: I'm glad that you have solved your problem. I edited the answer. Please accept the answer (click the check under the number of my answer if you don't know), I'm in need of some reputation to get desired feature. BTW, that's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: yes but problem is not gone I tryed your way but file can not be fined so I need the way to find the file = / I placed adding in my post please read and help if you can any way I will give you the points = ]

Comment: I don't know if File class (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) can handle this, but if the file in asset folder, maybe there's no way to check if it is exist. However, there's a trick: Just execute the code that load the image, but surrounds it with Try..Catch block, so if there's exception, it's because the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand why you need to sort resources that will be *static* in your APK, but you should not access them directly using paths, but using the API for that purpose.

Take a look at the topics in the dev guide here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Those will teach you how to access the resources. To create Bitmaps from them, the easiest way is to use the [`BitmapFactory` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29)

Remember, you *know* which resources the APK has at building time, so you can work around it. If you want to work with Bitmaps created at runtime, then use the [data storage methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) instead.